# How to loop a specific String Caesar Cipher vb10

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, encryption

I am creating a program with an encrypt and decrypt function. The problem is it should only work on the static string on the code. It should loop when the input plain text is the last. For example the String is "ABCDE...Z1234567890" when i input 0 and the key is 2 the Cipher text should be B. I have four textboxes for the key, the input, the plaintext and the ciphertext. Here's my code.

```
Public Class Form1
       Dim key As Integer
Const Intext As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
Private Sub btCipher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btCipher.Click

    Dim plain, s, r As String
    Dim i, j As Long
    key = Val(txtKey.Text)
    plain = txtInput.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(plain)
        r = Mid$(plain, i, 1)
        j = (InStr(1, Intext, r))
        If key > 36 Then
            s = s & Mid$(Intext, j + (key - 36), 1)
        Else
            s = s & Mid$(Intext, j + key, 1)
        End If

    Next i

    txtResult.Text = s
End Sub

Private Sub btDecipher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btDecipher.Click

    Dim plain, s, r As String
    Dim i, j As Long
    key = Val(txtKey.Text)
    plain = txtResult.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(plain)
        r = Mid$(plain, i, 1)
        j = (InStr(1, Intext, r))
        If key > 36 Then
            s = s & Mid$(Intext, j + (key - 36), 1)
        Else
            s = s & Mid$(Intext, j - key, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    txtText.Text = s
End Sub End Class
```

My Problem is its not looping. Maybe someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Is the `key` variable the number of characters that are skipped in the `Intext` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but try this code instead:

```
Public Class Form1

    Const Intext As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

    Private Function Transcode(text As String, map As Dictionary(Of Char, Char)) As String
        Return New String(text.Select(Function(x) If(map.ContainsKey(x), map(x), x)).ToArray())
    End Function

    Private Sub btCipher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btCipher.Click
        Dim key = Val(txtKey.Text)
        Dim map = _
            Intext _
                .Zip(Intext.ToCharArray().Concat(Intext.ToCharArray()).Skip(key), Function(f, t) New With {f, t}) _
                .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.f, Function(x) x.t)
        txtResult.Text = Transcode(txtInput.Text, map)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btDecipher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btDecipher.Click
        Dim key = Val(txtKey.Text)
        Dim map = _
            Intext _
                .Zip(Intext.ToCharArray().Concat(Intext.ToCharArray()).Skip(key), Function(f, t) New With {f, t}) _
                .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.t, Function(x) x.f)
        txtText.Text = Transcode(txtResult.Text, map)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've tested the algorithm and it works fine.

Comment: The code is working for the looping but the decipher button isn't working? i have four textboxes and i saw three on your code, how can i decipher? Maybe we can add textbox to the decipher result. Thank you. :)

Comment: @WarrenRazon - I took the textboxes directly from your question. You might need to check if you need to change any of them in my answer to make it work. You'll also notice that the `.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.f, Function(x) x.t)` calls are inverted on the two methods - one is `Function(x) x.f, Function(x) x.t` and the other `Function(x) x.t, Function(x) x.f`. That allows the decipher to go backwards. So I think you just have to get your text boxes right.

Comment: Ok, im sorry. I missed a name, it work now. But what if i have to add a new textbox on top and be the reference of the string ? **Const Intext As Double = txtString.Text** is my code it didn't work, what should i do ?

Comment: I also used this but it can't **Const Intext As String = "" + txtString.Text+ ""** it says that **"reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"**

Comment: @WarrenRazon - Yes, `Const Intext As String = "" + txtString.Text+ ""` can't be declared as a `Const` is a shared value across all classes and you're trying to assign to it a string based on an instance field. Try `Private` instead of `Const`.